# Sum of particular values in a Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, sum, ruby-hash

I have two hashes:

```
first = { 1 => [15, 15, 15, 8], 4 => [11, 12, 7, 7], 5 => [14, 17, 13, 13],
          6 => [19, 19, 15, 15], 7 => [5, 12, 12, 12], 8 => [10, 14, 14, 14], 
          9 => [8, 7, 8, 8] } 

second = { 1 => [0, 1, 2], 4 => [2, 3], 5 => [2, 3], 6 => [0, 1, 2, 3], 
           7 => [1, 2, 3], 8 => [1, 2, 3], 9 => [2, 3] }
```

As you see they both use same keys, but values are different. `second`'s values contains ranges of indexes of the `first`'s values and I need to sum only those `first`'s values that are in those ranges.

The expected output:

```
result = { 1 => [45], 4 => [14], 5 => [26], etc }
```

Comment: Explain this result = { 1 => [45], 4 => [14], 5 => [26], etc } properly

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? [so] is not a Write-My-Code-For-Me-Service. Those *do* exist, they are called "programmers" and you can hire them for a fee.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A straightforward way is to say exactly what you mean:

```
first.map { |k, v| [ k, [ v.values_at(*second[k]).sum ] ] }.to_h
```

If your version of Ruby doesn't have [`Array#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sum) then use `inject(:+)`:

```
first.map { |k, v| [ k, [ v.values_at(*second[k]).inject(:+) ] ] }.to_h
```

You could also skip the `map`/`to_h` business by using `each_with_object` instead:

```
first.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = [ v.values_at(*second[k]).inject(:+) ] }
```

A little time with the [`Array#values_at` documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-values_at) might be fruitful as would the [`Enumerable` documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html).

Comment: , why enclose each sum in an array? I see @llya did the same, so I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Because that's the format the question asked for. I agree that it looks a bit weird but...

Comment: Egad, how did I miss that?

Answer (score 3):

More natural way is to use `Hash#merge`, I think:

```
first.merge(second) { |_, f, s| [f.values_at(*s).sum] }
#=> {1=>[45], 4=>[14], 5=>[26], 6=>[68], 7=>[36], 8=>[42], 9=>[16]}
```

Of course, you can use `inject(:+)` instead of `sum` if your Ruby version < 2.4

Answer (score 2):

Since you say the elements of `second` are ranges, you might write them as such:

```
second = { 1=>0..2, 4=>2..3, 5=>2..3, 6=>0..3, 7=>1..3, 8=>1..3, 9=>2..3 }
```

Then

```
second.merge(second) { |k,o,_| first[k].values_at(*o).sum }
  #=> {1=>45, 4=>14, 5=>26, 6=>68, 7=>36, 8=>42, 9=>16}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all keys. See the doc for details, particularly the values of the three block variables `k`, `o`, and `n`. (Here I've replaced `n` with `_` to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def sum(list, indices)
    sum = 0
    indices.each do |index|
        sum += list[index]
    end
   return sum
end
```

And then

`second.map { |k, v| [k, sum(first[k], v)] }.to_h`